# how to deploy asp.net application after adding service reference without build the solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have multiple asp.net web application running in server. I want to change the service reference URL and i dont want to build the application. Please help how do i deploy? Thanks

Comment: Service reference URLs should be in the web.config file.

Comment: only i need to change the url in web.config file or any where else?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?